# Punycode Backend Server Issue

Tags: node.js, express-generator, punycode

When i try to run backend server using npx nodemon the issue comes:
DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created);

Note:"i have already downgraded version but no solution "

[THIS IS THE SCENE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuiqT.png)

I HAVE TRIED TO DOWNGRADE AND I HAVE DONE IT BUT
STILL NO ADVANTAGE

Comment: You need to downgrade *very far* or else do as node suggests. If you want to downgrade, look for a version from 2015. But before you do that, consider whether node's suggestion may be a good one.

Comment: Hi, using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you

Comment: Sir Which version is best and i dont know from where to download the old versions of node js